# OpenTelemetry collector export to Prometheus is not working

Tags: .net, .net-core, prometheus, open-telemetry

All,
I am trying to integrate OpenTelemetry collector with Prometheus in a .Net application. I am using OTLP Exporter in the application and running OpenTelemetry Collector as a windows service on same system.
Please find the below 'config.yaml' I am using for collector

```
extensions:
  health_check:
  pprof:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:1777
  zpages:
    endpoint: 0.0.0.0:55679

receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:
  prometheus:
    config:
      scrape_configs:
        - job_name: 'otel-collector'
          scrape_interval: 5s
          static_configs:
            - targets: [ 'localhost:55681' ]

processors:
  batch:

exporters:
  zipkin:
    endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:9411/api/v2/spans"
  prometheus:
    endpoint: "localhost:55681"
    namespace: promexample
    const_labels:
      label1: value1
  logging:
    logLevel: debug

service:

  pipelines:

    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging,zipkin]

    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp,prometheus]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [logging,prometheus]

  extensions: [health_check, pprof, zpages]
```

Here is the 'prometheus.yml'

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
  # scrape_timeout is set to the global default (10s).

# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      # - alertmanager:9093

# Load rules once and periodically evaluate them according to the global 'evaluation_interval'.
rule_files:
  # - "first_rules.yml"
  # - "second_rules.yml"

# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
    
  - job_name: 'otel-collector'
    scrape_interval: 10s
    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:55681']
```

I don't see the metrics exported to Prometheus. I am creating some counters programatically in the application and looking for the same in Prometheus.

Please note, I tried to export traces to Zipkin and it worked fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Prometheus UI target health is showing 'UP' as below.

[image]

Comment: You're sure that metrics are being received by the collector? I see you have the logging exporter for the metrics pipeline enabled. If prometheus shows the collector endpoint is up then the only thing I can think is that metrics aren't being received by the collector.

Comment: Thank for your reply Parker.

Comment: I tried exactly what you suggested. Tried to run the collector from console and I see only traces are received. Some reason the metrics are not received by collector.